# OSX equivalent to sudo chgrp -R www-data <directory>

Tags: mac-osx, chgrp

I normally do

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data <directory>
```

on Ubuntu to set a folder writable by the Apache process. What's the Mac OS X equivalent for `www-data`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On Ubuntu you use "www-data" because that is the user the Apache process runs as.  You can identify the user Apache will use by checking the config file.  On my Mac, it looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
[...]
User _www
Group _www
[...]
```

So one way to make your files writable would be to `chgrp` them to `_www`.